# R date filtering

Tags: r, date

I'm curious why R allows filtering for a specific date using a character vector, but it does NOT allow `%in%` with character vectors (it must be date object).

```
# create a dataframe for filtering 
df <- data.frame(
   'a' = letters,
   'date' = as.Date('2022-01-01') + 0:(length(letters)-1)
)
```

Using a character vector works when testing for equality

```
df[df$date == '2022-01-01',]
```

`a    date` 
`1 a 2022-01-01`

Using a character vector does NOT work with %in% (it doesn't make a difference if there are multiple values in the `c()`)

```
df[df$date %in% c('2022-01-01'),]
```

`[1] a    date`
`<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Using a date object works with %in%

```
df[df$date %in% as.Date(c('2022-01-01')),]
```

`a    date`
`1 a 2022-01-01`

Comment: It ccould be related to the conversion as mentione din the help page `"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0

Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, internally classed objects are transformed via mtfrm,`

Comment: `match(df$date, c('2022-01-01'), nomatch = 0)#
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`, which is due to the conversion changes with `mtfrm` `mtfrm(df$date)
 [1] 18993 18994 18995 18996 18997 18998 18999 19000 19001 19002 19003 19004 19005 19006 19007 19008 19009 19010 19011 19012 19013 19014 19015 19016
[25] 19017 19018#
> mtfrm(c('2022-01-01'))#
[1] "2022-01-01"`